# node.js objectmapper string to javascript object

Tags: node.js, javascript-objects

using object-mapper node.js module, to map a object to another.

```
var objectMapper = require('object-mapper');
var map = {"foo": [{ key:"newfoo", transform: function(value){ return "##"+value;  }}]}
var data =  {"foo":"bar","baz":"blah"}
var dest = objectMapper(data, map);
```

The variable `map` is dynamic and would vary based on scenario to scenario.
so i could have another translation as

```
{"foo": [{ key:"newfoo", transform: function(value){ return "$$"+value;  }}]}
```

I hold all templates by creating a javascript file map_tmpl.js

```
var tmpl_1= function () {return {"foo": [{ key:"newfoo", transform: function(value){ return "##"+value;  }}]};}
var tmpl_2= function () {return {"foo": [{ key:"newfoo", transform: function(value){ return "##"+value;  }}]};}
module.exports= {tmpl_1,tmpl_2}
```

I want to save these templates in a database and read from database when needed, 
If i store this as string and pass it to objectmapper, object-mapper does not work as it is expecting an object, kindly advice on the best way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSON knows nothing about function, you have to use custom serializer & deserializer for storing in / out database.

```
var serializer = function(key, val) {
   if (typeof val === 'function') return val + '';      /* serialize function to string */
   return val;
};

var deserializer = function(key, val) {
   var reg = /^function\s*\(/;      /* match function string and deserialize back to function */
   if (typeof val === 'string' && reg.test(val)) {
      eval(`var fn = ${val}`);
      return fn;
   }
   return val;  
}
```

And take example of your code:

1) save into database

```
var tmpl_1= function () {return {"foo": [{ key:"newfoo", transform: function(value){ return "##"+value;  }}]};}
var StringIntoDatabase = JSON.stringify(tmpl_1, serializer);
```

2) take from database

```
var tmpl_1 = JSON.parse(StringFromDatabase, deserializer);
```

Console snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Worked for me, not sure why the downvote. syntax error in deserializer, return val, instead of v.  `var deserializer = function(key, val) {
   var reg = /^function\s*\(/;      /* match function string and deserialize back to function */
   if (typeof val === 'string' && reg.test(val)) {
      eval(`var fn = ${val}`);
      return fn;
   }
   return val;    
}`

Comment: I think that was my downvote, but I don't remember doing it? I blame an overly sensitive touch screen on my phone. I've undone it.